# Javascript Switch Statement with more than one default

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm a beginner at JavaScript. I'm sorry if I cannot explain clearly what I need.

I am trying to design a page with some questions. The answers must be typed in a textbox.

I am using a Switch Statement to generate different comments to all acceptable answers.

As for answers that are not accepted, I would like to have more than the default message.

For example, if the user types an unaccepted answer for the first time, a message will show up, like "That is not an acceptable answer". On the user's second unaccepted answer a different message would show up, like "Please try again"... And so on for about five times, and then it would loop back to the first default message.

I just don't know how to make that happen...
This is what I have so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text;
  var colors = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  switch (colors) {
    case "White":
      text = "White is a nice color.";
      break;
    case "Blue":
      text = "I also like blue. It reminds me of the ocean.";
      break;
    case "Red":
      text = "Red is also nice.";
      break;
    default:
      text = "That is not an acceptable answer";
  }
  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>What is your favorite color from the USA flag?</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

Comment: Count the number of clicks, check that number, assign different string depending on that check.

Comment: var message = [ msg 1, msg 2, ... ]
var count = 0;

default: text = message[count]; count<message.lentgth-1?count++ : count = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an array for the number of messages, the user needs to get when they have sent an answer.

```
var count = 0;
var messages = ["That is not an acceptable answer.", "Please try again!", "Still wrong.", "I don't understand.", "Consider visiting the 'help page' before moving on."];
```

Based on that count, show the message in the `default` case.

```
default:
  text = messages[count%messages.length];
  count++;
```

**Full Working Snippet**

```js
var count = 0;
var messages = ["That is not an acceptable answer.", "Please try again!", "Still wrong.", "I don't understand.", "Consider visiting the 'help page' before moving on."];

function myFunction() {
  var text;
  var colors = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  switch (colors) {
    case "White":
      text = "White is a nice color.";
      break;
    case "Blue":
      text = "I also like blue. It reminds me of the ocean.";
      break;
    case "Red":
      text = "Red is also nice.";
      break;
    default:
      text = messages[count%messages.length];
      count++;
  }
  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>What is your favorite color from the USA flag?</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. But it seems that the "Full Working Snippet" that you posted doesn't work like it should. No matter how many times I write an unaccepted answer, the message is always the same. Can you please help me figuring this out? Thank you.

Comment: @MikeMichaels Sorry man... The problem is the scoping. I have updated it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Just one more thing, if that is not asking for too much of you... How do I add the other messages to default, besides those two? I am sorry if this is an obvious question. I am just taking my first steps here...

Comment: I am very sorry. I must be doing something wrong, or maybe I am not being able to express myself properly. If I trigger the default message twice, I will be shown two different messages indeed ("Please try again!" and "That is not an acceptable answer"), but if I keep on clicking it, the second message will keep showing up, until it loops back to the first one. What I would like to do, it to have 5 different messages for each click. I just don't know where to add the other three in the code...

Comment: @MikeMichaels Gotcha... Sorry man, I thought you need this way. Can you send me the 5 messages, I'll update them in the answer?

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very kind, sir.
1. "That is not an acceptable answer."
2. "Please try again!"
3. "Still wrong."
4. "I don't understand."
5. "Consider visiting the 'help page' before moving on."

Comment: Done. Thank you very much for your help and your patience.

Comment: @MikeMichaels No probs... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var counter = 0;
    function myFunction() {
        var text;
        var colors = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

        switch(colors) {
            case "White":
                text = "White is a nice color.";
            break;
            case "Blue":
            text = "I also like blue. It reminds me of the ocean.";
            break;
            case "Red":
            text = "Red is also nice.";
            break;
            default:
            text = getText(counter++);
        }
        counter = counter > 5 ? 0 : counter;
        document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
    }

function getText(counter) {
    switch(counter):
       case 1:
          return "some text";
       case 2:
          return "some text";
    ...
}
```